# How can make sort method of kendo in a dataSource?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a list of data that must be shown based their instrument volume.

For this purpose, I have defined a model as follows:

```
window.viewModels.hotListFiltersView = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
    filteredInstruments: new kendo.data.DataSource({
 sort: [{ field: 'instrument.volume', dir: 'desc' }], 
 data: [] }),

fillFilteredInstruments: function (item) {
        var self = viewModels.hotListFiltersView;
        findInstrument(item.insMaxCode, function (instrument) {
            if (instrument) {
                console.warn("instrument", instrument);
                self.filteredInstruments.insert(item.index, {
                                        
                    instrument: instrument,
                   
                });
            }
            self.filteredInstruments.fetch();
        });
    },

})
```

For filling the `filteredInstruments`, i have used the `fillFilteredInstruments`.

I have also defined findInstrument as a global method:

```
 function findInstrument(code, method, inSymbol) {
        var ins = dataSet.instruments._data.find(function (i) {
                return i.insMaxCode == code;
            });
        }
        method(ins || null);
    }
```

the instrument itself also is a DataSource and defined as a global variable as follows:

```
   dataSet.set("instruments", new kendo.data.DataSource({}));
```

I have a list of items that must be placed inside of filteredInstrumets:

```
 var insMaxCodes = [{insMaxCode:"1"},{insMaxCode:"2"},{insMaxCode:"3"}];
 subscribedCodes.forEach((item) => {
                viewModels.hotListFiltersView.fillFilteredInstruments(item);
            })
```

when the volume value is changed, the list is not sorted. the sort is not observable.
How can i solve this issue?